# how to calculate the volume of irregular shape by the Cartesian coordinates of its corners?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, volume

I've 4 points in a plane "A" and another 4 in another plane "B". is there a way to automatically calculate the volume contained into this irregular box? 
The automation is important as this set of 8 points will be input hundreds of times.
Thanks a lot of the help :)

Comment: It will depend on how the vertices are connected

Comment: In a general case, the easiest would be to [triangulate your object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(geometry)) and use e.g. some of [this expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume). This is not very fast, but it should be enough for "hundreds of times".